# Trying to put an attempt counter in a do while loop (Basic JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have this code

document.getElementById('attempts').value = 'Attempts: '+varattempts;

and its purpose is to record the user's # of attempts. I don't know where to insert it into my code to enable its use. If someone could show me where to put it, or modify it(?) that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>

</HEAD>

<BODY>


<FORM NAME="testform">
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" VALUE="Click to Guess" onClick="testButton(this.form)">
<BR>
<BR>
</FORM>

<INPUT id="attempts" TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="Attempts " />
<INPUT id="zero" TYPE="button" NAME="resetbox" VALUE="Reset " onclick="reset()" />


<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

varattempts = 0
x = Math.round((Math.random()*19))+1    
function testButton (form){

    var Guess;

    do

    {

    Guess = prompt("Pick a number between 1 and 20","")

    }

    while (Guess!=x);

    if (Guess == x)

    {

    alert("You guessed right!")

    }


}

function reset()

{
    varattempts=0;
    document.getElementById('attempts').value = 'Attempts: 0'; 
}


</SCRIPT>



</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: You don't have to test `if (Guess == x)` after `while`, since the loop continues until `Guess == x`.

Comment: I put it in there so it would display the alert. Is there a way I can display the alert upon guessing the right answer in the do-while

Comment: `Guess` is always equal to `x` *upon completion* of the loop, because the loop continues until `Guess` is equal to `x`.

Comment: Another way of putting it is that you can't get to the `if` block unless the condition in the `while` evaluates to true. So you don't need the `if`.

Comment: How do I display the alert "You guessed right!" in the do while if the user gets it

Comment: That's a lot of vertical whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will show the number of attempts. It also allows the user to cancel.

```
function testButton(form) {
  var Guess;
  document.getElementById('attempts').value = 0;
  do {

    Guess = prompt("Pick a number between 1 and 20", "")
    if (Guess === null) break;
    document.getElementById('attempts').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('attempts').value)+1
  } while (Guess != x);

  if (Guess == x) {
    alert("You guessed right!")
  }
}
```